# How to export ggplot in R with 3543 pixels in JPEG format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg, dpi

How to export ggplot with 3543 pixels (meaning: DPI resolution 1000 and 90 mm wide) in JPEG file?

I used this code but it does not function in my case:

jpeg(file="Traject_1.jpg", res=3543, width=9,  pointsize=7,
type="windows", antialias="cleartype")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ggsave`:

```
ggsave("Traject_1.jpg", plot = yourplotname, device = "jpeg", width = 90, units = "mm", dpi = 1000)
```

Documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html).

(NB: 1000 dpi is super high!)